# Controller endpoint posted object is missing a field

Tags: c#, .net-5, asp.net5

I have a controller endpoint where the value posted to it has a `location` field, but it is missing in the posted object inside the Controller. See there is no location field in `Establishment`:

[image]

But the `FashionPlaceDto` does have a `Location`:

```
namespace Vepo.Domain
{
    public class FashionPlaceDto : EstablishmentDto<FashionItemEstablishmentDto> {
    }
}
```

base:

```
namespace Vepo.Domain
{
    [Serializable]
    public class EstablishmentDto : Dto<int>
    {
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string PlaceId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Street { get; set; }
        public string Suburb { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string StreetNumber { get; set; }
        public Vepo.Application.Location Location { get; set; }

    }

    public class EstablishmentDto<TVeganItemEstablishmentDto> : EstablishmentDto
        where TVeganItemEstablishmentDto : VeganItemEstablishmentDto
    {
        [PropertyName("veganItemEstablishments", Ignore = true)]
        public virtual ICollection<TVeganItemEstablishmentDto> VeganItemEstablishments { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The Location field type:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Vepo.Application
{
    public interface ILocation
    {
        double Lat { get; set; }
        double Lng { get; set; }
    }
    public class Location
    {
        public Location(double lat, double lng)
        {
            this.Lat = lat;
            this.Lng = lng;
        }

        [Required]
        public double Lat { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public double Lng { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The object posted to the endpoint does have a `location`:

[image]

So why does the posted object not have the `Location` inside my controller?

EDIT: For Ben -

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using Nest;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace Vepo.Domain
{
    [Serializable]
    public class VeganItemEstablishmentDto : Dto<int> 
    {
        [Required]
        public int VeganItemId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int EstablishmentId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int NotInEstablishmentCount { get; set; } = 0;
        [Required]
        public int InEstablishmentCount { get; set; } = 0;
        [Required]
        public double Price { get; set; }
    }

    public class VeganItemEstablishmentDto<TVeganItemDto, TEstablishmentDto> : VeganItemEstablishmentDto
        where TVeganItemDto : VeganItemDto
        where TEstablishmentDto : EstablishmentDto
    {
        public TVeganItemDto VeganItem { get; set; }
        public TEstablishmentDto Establishment { get; set; }
    }
}
```

EDIT: I kinda get the feeling the whole project is not building so some of the project is "old". Because this is happening:

[image]

And I only just added the Location recently. So maybe the code is just not in the built programme anymore. I am researching how I can fix this. And I'm unsure why it stopped working as I didn't change my build process. It is building in VS Code with a launch.json file.

Comment: Where is the `Location` field in your image? And why posting image, when you can copy the object's values as JSON and paste them here. Also, I don't understand why do you think this has anything to do with EF Core. It's more likely to be some deserialization problem.

Comment: @StefanGolubović well the location field has a yellow ring around it in the bottom image so I assume you saw that. Why would the location field be on the other image? The whole issue is that it’s not there?

Comment: @StefanGolubović because I’m using EF Core? If I knew the reason for the issue I would probably have solved it by now?

Comment: You didn't post anything that has to do with EF Core. And again, if you're missing a field or the field has value `null` in a DTO in a Controller when you are expecting value, you should check your app setup, `JsonSerializer` config or anything that has to do with (de)serialization. From the first image I can see that you're calling some service, which uses EF Core's persistence `Context` or delegates work to Data Access layer, so it's definitely not related to EF Core.

Answer (score 0):

Well bugger, the project was running in an old state because I had upgraded to .NET 6 and the `launch.json` file needed to be updated. Sorry for the lost time :( I can't delete this though due to the bounty so I will just have to post my solution...not sure if I should change the whole title and everything or what..

launch.json: (look for "THIS LINE HAD TO CHANGE TO REFER TO .NET6 AFTER THE UPGRADE!!" for the bit that changed)

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            // Use IntelliSense to find out which attributes exist for C# debugging
            // Use hover for the description of the existing attributes
            // For further information visit https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/blob/master/debugger-launchjson.md
            "name": ".NET Core Launch (web)",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "build",
            // THIS LINE HAD TO CHANGE TO REFER TO .NET6 AFTER THE UPGRADE!!
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/Vepo.Web/bin/Debug/net6.0/Vepo.Web.dll",
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/Vepo.Web",
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            // Enable launching a web browser when ASP.NET Core starts. For more information: https://aka.ms/VSCode-CS-LaunchJson-WebBrowser
            "serverReadyAction": {
                "action": "openExternally",
                "pattern": "\\\\bNow listening on:\\\\s+(https?://\\\\S+)"
            },
            "env": {
                "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
            },
            "sourceFileMap": {
                "/Views": "${workspaceFolder}/Views"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Attach",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "attach",
            "processId": "${command:pickProcess}"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I think this highlights the woefully under-utlised "Clean and Build".

When it comes to problem solving, Occams Razor should be applied;

Remove all likely scenarios, moving onto the least likely. Whatever remains, however unlikely, must be the issue.

So when it comes to this issue, the first thing I'd have done is check;
- Am I passing the correct data?
- Is the property accessible publicly?
- Has the project built correctly (clean solution and then rebuild)

Answer (score 0):

As I remember Dto classes must have parameterless constructor. So if i right you should just add to your location class:

```
public Location()
{

}
```

Other DTO classes works because compiler creates parameterless constructor by default if you does not defined your own.